# Matrix for rotation about axis in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations

The following are the matrices that represent rotations anticlockwise about the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axis respectively:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & 0 & \sin\theta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
My question is, when we say *anticlockwise* what exactly do we mean?

Do we mean anticlockwise when facing in the positive direction of the given axis or anticlockwise when facing in the negative direction of the given axis?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What happens when you set $\theta$ to some small angle like 30 degrees and observe the action of these matrices on standard basis vectors?

Comment: BTW: the result will depend on whether you have chosen to work with left-handed or right-handed coordinate system.

Comment: @AdamZalcman I'm not sure what you mean by your second comment, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)

Comment: @AdamZalcman I don't really understand Wikipedia's explanation, would you mind explaining what it is please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a “standard” right-handed coordinate system, it means if you stick the thumb of your right hand in the positive direction of the axis, the rotation is in the direction of the curl of your fingers.

Were we using the alternative left-handed system, the rotation would be in the other direction.

Edit: We say that the system is right-handed if, when your right thumb is pointing straight up in the positive z direction, and your right fingers are pointing in the positive x direction, your fingers curl in the direction of positive y. When you use your left hand to determine positive y, you get a left-handed system.

Comment: Wouldn't that be clockwise?

Comment: So it looks anticlockwise only if you look in the negative direction of the given axis?

Comment: Yes, it looks anticlockwise when looking down on your right thumb

Comment: Or said differently, pretend your thumb is part of a sundial to form the “clock” we’re comparing against.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! As an aside, would you mind explaining the difference between right and left handed coordinate systems? I didn't really understand the wikipedia article.

Comment: So if I'm using my left hand and my thumb and index figure are pointing towards the positive x and y axis respectively, then my raised middle finger is pointing in the negative z direction, and that's a left handed system?

Comment: So the middle finger would be pointing in the negative y direction?

Comment: I rewrote my edit to hopefully make things less confusing

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thanks for your patience and time, I really appreciate it!!